# Remote Access Linux Box - udp hole punch?

Tags: linux, remote-access

I was wondering if someone could help me shed some light on a particular problem I'm trying to solve.

The general idea is that I have a web application running on localhost (linux machine).  I'd like to have an option for a user to click a button that would open a remote tunnel with a host so the box could be administrated from outside the localhost's network.  Encrypting the conversation would be ideal as well.

Is there an opensource project that deals with this client/server type setup that could help me?  Any pointers in a direction that is beneficial would be greatly appreciated.

I know this can be done, just wondering what tools or areas of concern I should concentrate on.

Comment: google "ssh", "vnc", "OpenVPN". do you want the user to use a special client or the browser ?  Easiest secure and most common solution would be, to use an ssh client to open a tunnel between the users computer and the box and than connect the users browser (or other client) to the users endpoint of the tunnel.

Comment: Or just use ssh and do the admin via commandline (and/or X11 tunnel).